# Does VS Code run in debug mode for 'ng serve'?

Tags: angular, typescript, vscode-debugger

Been trying to get VS Code to run in debug mode for the project.

I've never used VS Code to do this before but the browser debugger is not showing me values for variables in the console.

So I figured I'd try to run VS Code under Debug mode. The breakpoints remain hollow. I can load the site under localhost:4200 but breakpoints I've put throughout never get hit.

Is there a special setting that must be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get this to work.

I had to start the application using the 'ng serve' command.

then using the 5th Icon Debug Arrow in this image.
[image: debug arrow]

I clicked on the Green Arrow in this image to Launch Chrome and the breakpoints now work.
[image: green arrow]

I'm not sure if VS Code allows for interacting with the variables like the browser debugger where you can run commands against them. But that's a different topic.

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to get this to work for over an hour. All the tutorials mention your second step (running "launch chrome" via the "run and debug" tab). But now that I do `ng serve` first, it's finally hitting breakpoints after running from the "run and debug" tab.

Comment: ^^ However, when running this way, then logging in via google within my app, I now get this error: "This browser or app may not be secure. Try using a different browser." That error occurs for Chrome and Brave.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `debugger` keyword on the code you want to debug. Then in the browser just open the developer panel/inspection panel. When the code executes you'll see the breakpoint getting hit.

Comment: You're saying in order for VS Code to debug I have to add 'debugger' statements to the code in order for the browser to see and hit breakpoints?

Comment: I thought we just need to add the breakpoint to the column to the Left of the code in VS Code and under the NPM SCRIPT select the debug option for the package script I want to run.

Comment: It depends on what you're developing. `ng serve` means you're developing a web-app that's hosted on localhost:4200, so you need to use the browser console. If you are developing a library then it's a different story.

Comment: For a library you will want to have some code that will run that library, where you can execute `ng serve` and again hit those debuggers on the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        // "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${file}",
        "type": "chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
         "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/out/**/*.js"
        ],
        "protocol": "inspector"
    }
]
```

}

use this in your launch.json file and press F5
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqrKO.png)

Comment: Where do I create the launch.json file? Under my src folder?

Comment: @edjm its already available in the project, inside .vscode folder, and if the folder is not present you can create a folder named ".VSCODE" and inside that create a file launch.json, {image updated above}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).